# Customize Android Notification layout and click of elements

Tags: android, layout, notifications

I want to show image from Url in notification panel for that purpose I am trying to make custom UI with following code but its not working

```
  int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");
    notification.contentView = contentView;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

and how I can handle the click of each element like image TextView etc.  I haven't found any stuff to handle click of each element.

Comment: you can not have multiple engaging points in notification. For that you can add multiple action button only which will be rendered in the bottom of notification. Refer this screenshot: http://developer.android.com/images/ui/notifications/notification_drawer.png

Comment: @Aditya That is not correct. You can supply a RemoteViews object to define the content view of the notification instead of using the system template.

Comment: ya but in remote views also, you can not give multiple engaging points. You can give only one click event to entire notification(Remote Views).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(viewId, pendingIntent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent(int,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) to give click actions to views in your RemoteViews object. This will allow you to do things like start a Service or send a broadcast (to be received by a BroadcastReceiver).

Comment: i have many views in layout , viva this i can do full click of notification na

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. This method takes the id of a view in the layout. Conceivably you can use `setOnClickPendingIntent(viewId, pendingIntent)` on every view in the layout as long as those views all have an id.